# On Bertrand's Postulate

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, distribution-of-primes

By Bertrand's postulate, we know that there exists at least one prime number between $n$ and $2n$ for any $n > 1$. In other words, we have
$$
\pi(2n) - \pi(n) \geq 1,
$$
for any $n > 1$.
The assertion we would like to prove is that the number of primes between $n$ and $2n$ tends to $\infty$ , if $n \to \infty$, that is,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \pi(2n) - \pi(n) = \infty.
$$
Do you see an elegant proof?

Comment: If a proof using the prime number theorem qualifies, there should be an easy and elegant proof.

Comment: I've shown $\frac{\pi(2n)}{\pi(n)} \to 2$ using PNT.

Answer (score 1):

By the PNT, we expect

$$\frac{2n}{\ln(2n)}-\frac{n}{\ln(n)}$$

$$=\frac{2n\ln(n)-n\ln(2n)}{\ln(2n)\ln(n)}$$

$$\sim\frac{n}{\ln(n)}$$

$$\to\infty,\;\; \text{as}\;\; n\to\infty$$

primes in this region.